# Calendar Block with node teaser display

Tags: views, ajax

Is this possible to create a calendar (using the Calendar module) with this functionality via Views:
 - Calendar is displaying month
 - days contain number (number of nodes in this day)
 - when I click the day, node teasers are loaded below calendar (ajax maybe?)

Do you think that with Event Calendar module I can achieve this?

Thanks.